# maven ear with war overlay

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, war

i have following war project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    ...

    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sixgroup.rdx.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>rdx-common-web</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sixgroup.rdx.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>rdx-common-web</artifactId>
            <version>${rdx-common.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <classifier>classes</classifier>
        </dependency>

        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>3.3</version> -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>com.sixgroup.rdx.common</groupId>
                            <artifactId>rdx-common-web</artifactId>
                            <exludes>
                                <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</exclude>
                                <exclude>WEB-INF/classes/**/*.class</exclude>
                            </exludes>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

this generates a beautiful war with the common-web .xhtml Files in the root dir and the classes of the common-web as jar in the web-inf/lib folder.

But now when i build the ear, the overlay of this war is ignored, so the excludes don't work and because of this i get an error when deploying (`A component named 'FooBar' is already defined in this module`)

This is the webModule in my ear-pom:

```
<webModule>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>rdp-pricedata-web</artifactId>
    <bundleFileName>rdp-pricedata-web.war</bundleFileName>
    <unpack>true</unpack>
</webModule>
```

is there a way to force the ear to accept the overlay in the war?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720479/building-ear-from-a-single-maven-project/41721766#41721766

Comment: @EssexBoy i don't think i can use the solution you commented, because here i have a war with an overlay

Comment: I don't think there is a way. I can only suggest to either move your resources to a separate module or build a separate archive that'll contain only what you need.

Comment: You build the war or war overlay that has a GAV (Group, Artifact, Version) in it's own right, then you have a dependency to that in your ear project ... simples :)