# Dependent maven projects compilation failure

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a maven project that depends on another local maven project. For example Project A depends on ProjectB

Directory layout:

```
-TopDir
  -DivergedDir
    -someSubDir
      -ProjectA pom.xml

-TopDir
  -subDir2
    -ProjectB pom.xml
```

In my Project A pom.xml I have:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>projectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectB-artifact</artifactId>
      <version>projectB-version</version>
   </dependency>
```

When compiling project A I have to do the following:
  1) go to project B directory and run `mvn install && mvn compile`
  2) go to project A directory and run `mvn compile`

Is there a way I can run mvn compile in project A directly without have to go to directory of projectB first? As in reference Project B from Project A in a different way?

Comment: read about Multi module projects

Comment: Look at this as a simple example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720479/building-ear-from-a-single-maven-project/41721766#41721766

Comment: These seem to only work with a parent base directory. However in my case the TopDir does not contain a pom.xml

Comment: You could always either create a parent, or promote project A to the parent of B