# Exporting EAR file with Eclipse manually

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, ear

I'm using gui (Eclipse IDE) to create EAR file for my project.
[image: export wizard]

How to launch eclipse in verbose mode or how to inspect which command was executed under the hood during generation?
I mean in the future I would like to build from the command line without opening an IDE. How can I do that? Also is there some Maven equivalent of doing that?

Comment: Is this a maven project? It would be better to use a maven-ear-plugin instead of relying on the black magic of your IDE. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/

Comment: Much easer in maven look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720479/building-ear-from-a-single-maven-project/41721766#41721766)

Comment: No, it's not a maven project (at least yet). That's why I want to how the underlying command being invoked.

Comment: You should change the packaging of your project into `ear` and define the version of the maven-ear-plugin in your pom and finally you will get an ear...But you have to have more modules cause usually an EE project contains at least one other part like an EJB or WAR or something else...