# Creating exploded JAR file with Configuration files

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jar, ear

How do I create a Jar File in Maven with the following structure:

`myjar.jar
        |-- configuration.xml
        |-- foo.xml
        |-- bar.xml`

So my goal is to put these configuration files into an exploded JAR file of the EAR (e.g. lib/myjar.jar/*.xml)

Comment: look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720479/building-ear-from-a-single-maven-project/41721766#41721766)

Comment: You just need to have these files in the `src/main/resources` directory of your jar project.